# Is it common to have a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error on a site you're developing, even though it wasn't there before?

Tags: ajax, cors, axios

I'm making a site with uses axios alongside react to grab data from this page: https://api.warframestat.us/pc

From there, I was able to build some react components to grab the data. Suddenly, as of today, I had to install a chrome plugin to be able to view the backend data, even though I made no changes to the site, only created a new .js file which doesn't do anything yet. Even when I deleted that file, the error remained. I looked at the console, and surely enough, I saw the Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue.

So the error has apparently come from nowhere. Is this common?

Comment: I just tested that API and there is indeed an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header so not sure why you're seeing an error. Maybe they decided to remove access for your domain / IP?

Comment: I suggest you look in your browser's _Network_ console. Analyse closely the requests / responses and their headers.

Comment: Hello Phil, it seems to be working again, so maybe it was a glitch. Thanks.